# typescript issue when using plain jsdoc types

Tags: javascript, types, jsdoc, typescript-eslint

Hi Im not using typescript or tsconfig.json
but JSDoc types as understood by vscode // @tscheck
I am looking for a Javscript-only solution with JSDoc type comments.

I followed the ideas in https://medium.com/@trukrs/type-safe-javascript-with-jsdoc-7a2a63209b76
and it's been working well generally but:

node   v16.17.0, vscode 1.74.0

```
    // @tscheck 

    /** @type {string} myTestString */   
    const myTestString = ("2022-01-12").replaceAll("-", "")
```

Error:
`Property 'replaceAll' does not exist on type 'string'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2021' or later.ts(2550)`

**How to fix this message without a build step?**
First I removed the // tscheck.  which killed the message,
but want to keep the type checking if possible.

In pure typescript there seems to be this suggestion
https://pinoria.com/how-to-fix-the-property-replaceall-does-not-exist-on-type-string-error-with-typescript/

but how to do similar without a build step?

Comment: Try using `("2022-01-12").replace(/-/g, "")`. `/-/g` is a regex pattern for all `-`.

Comment: Thanks Abrar that is very good, but I 'm hoping to keep the replaceAll()
For me, the idea is to use and explore the jsdsoc type system.